# Concat multible props in React in a title attribute

Tags: reactjs

How can i concat multiple props in a title attribute ?
I also tried:

```
 title=[{pep.first_Name}{pep.first_Name}]


 title={pep.first_Name}{pep.first_Name}
```

Comment: title={\`${pep.first_Name}${pep.first_Name}\`}

Comment: Or `title={pep.first_name + " " + pep.first_name}`.

Comment: This is a basic misunderstanding of syntax. In JSX: `{}` denotes a JavaScript expression.Using `[]` is most likely a syntax error as well as using multiple `{}{}` together like that. You simply need to open up an expression with `{}`, and then use regular JavaScript inside to combine the props into a single string. Either method above is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thx at all. No it works :)